# jQuery FullCalendar stuck in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I finally got the drag and drop deletion working. Now the problem is, when I delete an event, the deletion works fine, but after it keeps looping inside the eventDragStop and the calendar freezes up.

```
eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
if (isElemOverDiv(ui.offset, '#event-delete')) {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the right solution however I have solved the problem modifying fullcalendar.js as follows:

```
function eachEventElement(event, exceptElement, funcName) {
    if(elements){
        var elements = eventElementsByID[event._id],
            i, len = elements.length;
        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if (!exceptElement || elements[i][0] != exceptElement[0]) {
                elements[i][funcName]();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    if (isElemOverDiv(ui, $('div.event-delete'))) {
        calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
    }
}
```

I got this from [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/javascript-15/jquery-fullcalendar-delete-event-via-drag-drop-748533.html) if it helps at all. I think it has something to do with `$('#calendar')`.

Comment: Nah that code is mine as well look at the username. I've fixed that problem but now I'm onto this one. calendar or $('#calendar') work the same for me. Thanks though :)

Comment: except that you are calling `$('#calendar')` in the function which might be your problem while they are using calendar which seems to come from the function.